# Adding italicised r with correlation coefficient to a scatter plot chart in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, expression, scatter-plot

I'm trying to use the code below to generate a simple scatter plot with a correlation coefficient that would have italicised *r* placed on the plot.

```
data(mtcars)

# Load required libraries
require(ggplot2)               # To derive the graphs
require(ggthemes)              # To apply ggplot themes to the chart
require(scales)                # For pretty breaks

# Function to generate correlation coefficient for the charts
corr_eqn <- function(x,y, digits = 2) {
  corr_coef <- round(cor(x, y), digits = digits)
  corr_coef <- expression(paste(italic(r)," = ", corr_coef))
  return(corr_coef)
}

# Provide a scatter plot for income and health deprivation
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = drat, y = wt)) +
  geom_point(shape = 19, size = 2, aes(colour = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_smooth(colour = "red", fill = "lightgreen", method = 'lm') +
  ggtitle("Example") +
  xlab("drat") +
  ylab("wt") +
  scale_colour_tableau("tableau10") +
  geom_text(x = 3, y = 3,
            label = corr_eqn(mtcars$drat,
                             mtcars$wt), parse = TRUE) +
  theme(legend.key = element_blank(),
        legend.background = element_rect(colour = 'black'),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(lineheight = .8, face = "bold", vjust = 1),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11, vjust = 0.5,
                                   hjust = 1, colour = 'black'),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11, colour = 'black'),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 10, face = 'bold'),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        plot.background = element_rect(colour = 'black', size = 1),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

The code stops with the `?` mark in console. Running the code with the lines:

```
#   geom_text(x = 3, y = 3,
#             label = corr_eqn(mtcars$drat, mtcars$wt), parse = TRUE) +
```

commented, generates the following chart:
[image: scatter plot]

I'm guessing that my function to generate equation of the format *r* = 0.7 does not work, how can I fix it?

Comment: Have a look on [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7549694/707145).

Comment: @MYaseen208 as a matter of fact, I was trying to write my function using discussion in the linked question but it doesn't work. Clearly, I did something wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you suspected, you just need to tweak your function.  You could have used `substitute` as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7549819/2461552), but you can also just use `paste` here.

```
corr_eqn <- function(x,y, digits = 2) {
  corr_coef <- round(cor(x, y), digits = digits)
  paste("italic(r) == ", corr_coef)
}
```

[image]

Note that if you'd added `as.character` to what your original function returned things would have parsed.  However, the result would have been with `corr_coef` as a string instead of the actual correlation coefficient you wanted.

I should also add that `geom_text` can result in poor resolution if you don't put the labels and coordinates into a new data.frame.

```
labels = data.frame(x = 3, y = 3, label = corr_eqn(mtcars$drat, mtcars$wt))
```

Then use the `data` argument and `aes` for `geom_text`:

```
geom_text(data = labels, aes(x = x, y = y,
                        label = label), parse = TRUE)
```

See `annotate` with `geom = "text"` as another option that avoids the new data.frame.

Comment: thank you very much for the comprehensive answer. Would it be very difficult to adjust the fonts, for instance by changing size and the font face?

Comment: @Konrad You can definitely change the font size and family for the label in `geom_text` using the `size` and `family` arguments when using `parse = TRUE`, but not the font face.

Comment: `corr_eqn <- function(x,y, digits = 2) {
+     corr_coef <- round(cor(x, y), digits = digits)
+     paste("italic(r) == ", corr_coef)
+ }
labels = data.frame(x = 3, y = 3, label = corr_eqn(mtcars$drat, mtcars$wt))` produces a df with only one row ` x y               label
 3 3 italic(r) ==  -0.71`

Comment: Just to emphasize the point made by aosmith, It's not just that the labels must be stored in a dataframe, but they must also be passed as such inside ``geom_text``, or to put it differently, passing ``labels$label`` to ``geom_text`` is not good enough.